# Add empty "separator" row to databound WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a databound DataGrid, and I want to have some kind of dummy rows to act as separators between various rows that I'm trying to somehow group together. However, even adding a new row by creating a new instance of the object (with no set-up, just calling an empty constructor) and adding it to the ObservableCollection seems to fill the cells that correspond to the int properties with 0.

Is there a way to have a dummy completely empty row or some other kind of separator in a databound WPF DataGrid? I would hate to have to go to an unbound one, adding everything manually to a dataset and everything. I've done this manually, I just don't want to have to go through that again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some sort of Group property on your source data

```
public class MyDataItem
{
     public string Group { get; set; }  // <-- assuming something like this exists
}
```

Make your DataGrid's `ItemsSource` be an `ICollectionView` and enable [Grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.groupdescriptions.aspx)

Then you can style the resulting groups to look like empty spaces (see [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/) for an example of how to style groups in the DataGrid)

Comment: Great tutorial. Thanks for the link. I was just about to post I was thinking about a workaround with "row details" being constantly shown for some rows as a separator, but this will do.