# How to set datagrid row's background based on variably value in cell

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, datagrid, rows

I am currently working with C# WPF `DataGrid`.
`DataGrid` is using my database as `ItemsSource` and I am using `DataGrid` to list my Orders.
For example:

> BIG BURGER   1
>   BIG MAC      1
>   CHEESEBURGER 1
>
> MCNUGGETS    2
>   CHICKEN      2
>   COCA-COLA    2
>   PEPSI        2

as you can see I am listing items from each order, and next to each item there is the number 1 or the number 2. Those numbers, are helping me to orient **which item belong to which order.**

My question is how could I paint each row, which items belong to specific order , for example red when items are associated with order 1, blue when items are associated with orders 2 and so on. Or, as an alternative, to paint only last row of each order (look at bold part below).

I need to separate them somehow, because when I load them to datagrid it looks messy.

Imagine this:

> BIG BURGER   1 
>   BIG MAC      1
>   ***CHEESEBURGER 1***
>   MCNUGGETS    2
>   CHICKEN      2
>   COCA-COLA    2
>   ***PEPSI        2***
>   BIG BURGER   3
>   BIG MAC      3
>   CHEESEBURGER 3
>   ***MCNUGGETS    3***
>   CHICKEN      4
>   COCA-COLA    4
>   ***PEPSI        4***

It looks pretty messy..

(as I said before is it possible to paint only last row of each order, just to create visible separation on screen, if whole rows is not possible.)

This is what I have until now but this is not optimal, because it uses hard coded values:

```
 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow"> 
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberOfOrder}"  Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberOfOrder}"  Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberOfOrder}"  Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

            datagrid1.ItemsSource = OrdersController.localOrders();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here as you can see I am using hard coded values, in case my `NumberOfOrder` is 1,2 or 3 **do next:** **paint rows**, and this is not good solution because I will have many different values for `NumberOfOrder`.

EDIT AFTER Mat's answer:

```
public MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponent();

    CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

    var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders(); //ORDERS LIST

    collectionViewSource.Source = new List<OrdersController.OrdersLocal>()
    {
        foreach(var item in ordersList) 
        {
            new OrdersController.OrdersLocal() {Title = item.Title, NumberOfOrder = item.NumberOfOrder, Desc = item.Desc,   User = item.User }
        }

    };

    collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));

    DataContext = collectionViewSource;
}
```

Comment: .. ..Anyone? :(

Comment: ah now i get it ;-) You can do it much more simpler: collectionViewSource.Source =ordersList; or if you want to use OrdersLocal class you can to a LINQ query: collectionViewSource.Source= ordersList.Select(x => new OrdersLocal() {Title = x.Title });

Comment: Thanks bro, that's awesome, btw is it possible to put some text (like header text of each group) when I collapse order so someone who is using app can see what it is about even if order is collapsed. for example I click collapse but I want to see text like this Order : numberofOrder, so I can orient which order I collapsed :)

Comment: hmm :))  could you help me with this header text of grouped items? Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to modify the ControlTemplate for the GroupItem. I suggest you make a new question to so as this may get confusing for others if we mix up all the follow up question you have

Comment: That is true Mat, thanks again my friend :)

Comment: new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741830/wpf-how-to-set-datagrid-group-header-text-when-its-acctualy-collapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CollectionViewSource and group by NumberOfOrder:
XAML:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

codebehind:

```
 CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        collectionViewSource.Source = new List<RowItem>()
            {
              new RowItem() {NumberOfOrder =1, Name ="kong foo" },
              new RowItem() {NumberOfOrder =1,Name ="asdf" },
              new RowItem() {NumberOfOrder =2,Name ="asdf" },
              new RowItem() {NumberOfOrder =3,Name ="foo"}
            };


        collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));

        DataContext = collectionViewSource;
```

Comment: further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Mat, you coment was so useful! Soon I will post my code, I am still having trouble but I will try to solve this!

Comment: Mat, how could I apply foreach loop here, in your example you showed me how I can solve this with 4 objects, but imagine I have a lot object in database, and how could I loop here each object and add it as new RowItem, I tried allready but I am having error that says: "INVALID INITIALIZER..."

Comment: RowItem is just an example class you can replace it with e.g. MyDataBaseRowItem. This how you get the data from database? do you use any ORM (Entity Framework or similar)? Then you have already a list of objects you can use...

Comment: Yes I understand, thats what I did, let me post code, I will edit my question right now so you can check what I am talking about :)

Comment: And I highly recommend you to take a look at the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124376/discussion-between-roxypro-and-mat).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use binding with a value converter to do so.

I did it for cell styles this way:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{Binding State, Converter={x:Static l:Converters.CoupleStateConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
```

So the converter returns background colors depending on the state (int in my example). This is similar to you needs.

As you see, the data context of the cell is the value of the row, so I can bind to the Property State in my example. I assume the same is valid for the row, so the data context will be the item to be displayed in this row.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [MultiDataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) to change the background based on a) order number and b) last row of order.  You would probably want to add a property in your model that says whether or not that row is the last row for that order.

Try something like this (untested):

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding NumberOfOrder}" Value="1" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsLastRow}" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    ...
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Nope, its not working this way :/, what happens when I load 5 orders at same time? Should `IsLastRow` recognize last row of each order? and paint it ?

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted, last row for each order to be different.  What do you want?  Blank rows?

Comment: I'm asking you that,  should it recognize last row of each order even if all of orders came in same time (for example five orders), that method will still recognize which row is last row of each other and paint it?

Comment: [Here on another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457845/add-empty-separator-row-to-databound-wpf-datagrid) the OP wants a way to group rows by order number and then style in a separator.  Something like that?

Comment: I'd go with @Mat 's answer, he's got a nice example of how to use the grouping.